# Getting a grid of a matrix via logical indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix-indexing

I'm trying to rewrite a function using numpy which is originally in MATLAB. There's a logical indexing part which is as follows in MATLAB:

```
X = reshape(1:16, 4, 4).';
idx = [true, false, false, true];
X(idx, idx)

ans =

     1     4
    13    16
```

When I try to make it in numpy, I can't get the correct indexing:

```
X = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4, 4)
idx = [True, False, False, True] 
X[idx, idx]
# Output: array([6, 1, 1, 6])
```

What's the proper way of getting a grid from the matrix via logical indexing?

Comment: I notices that I can do it via `X[idx,:][:,idx]` but isn't that weird?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also write:

```
>>> X[np.ix_(idx,idx)]
array([[ 1,  4],
       [13, 16]])
```

Comment: +1; Didn't know about `np.ix_`. However, this approach has worse performance (2x) than "regular indexing".

Comment: @root: this is different from your approach since it allows the sliced matrix to be modified, while yours give read-only access: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-13d7391dd7e2c57d293809cff080260b46d8e664

Comment: True, true. You may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: Somehow I don't see the difference between the two approaches, can you give an example that illustrates the difference?

Comment: @Akavall -- Amro's supports assignment, while mine is faster; so they have different usecases. That is `X[np.ix_(idx, idx)]=np.zeros((2,2))` modifies the original array, but `X[idx][:,idx]=np.zeros((2,2))` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: X = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4, 4)

In [2]: idx = np.array([True, False, False, True])  # note that here idx has to
                                                    # be an array (not a list)
                                                    # or boolean values will be 
                                                    # interpreted as integers

In [3]: X[idx][:,idx]
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [13, 16]])
```

Comment: +1 I did not know that transforming the `ìdx` list to an array would allow the correct indexing using `x[idx]`

Answer (score 2):

In `numpy` this is called `fancy indexing`. To get the items you want you should use a `2D` array of indices.

You can use an `outer` to make from your 1D `idx` a proper `2D` array of indices. [The outers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), when applied to two `1D` sequences, compare each element of one sequence to each element of the other. Recalling that `True*True=True` and `False*True=False`, the `np.multiply.outer()`, which is the same as `np.outer()`, can give you the `2D` indices:

```
idx_2D = np.outer(idx,idx)
#array([[ True, False, False,  True],
#       [False, False, False, False],
#       [False, False, False, False],
#       [ True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Which you can use:

```
x[ idx_2D ]
array([ 1,  4, 13, 16])
```

In your real code you can use `x=[np.outer(idx,idx)]` but it does not save memory, working the same as if you included a `del idx_2D` after doing the slice.

Comment: You don't save any memory by not assigning that intermediate array to a variable: it gets created, used, and then discarded. The same as if you wrote a `del idx_2D` after the indexing.