# Numpy indexing with a one dimensional boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, octave

The post, [Getting a grid of a matrix via logical indexing in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17335993/1281433), is similar, but it does not answer my question since I am working with a one dimensional boolean array.

I am attempting to recreate the following boolean indexing feature in Octave.

```
octave-3.2.4:6> a = rand(3,3)
a =

   0.249912   0.934266   0.371962   
   0.505791   0.813354   0.282006 
   0.439417   0.085733   0.886841  
octave-3.2.4:8> a([true false true])
ans =

    0.24991   0.43942
```

However, I am unable to create the same results in Python with Numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(3,3)
array([[ 0.94362993,  0.3553076 ,  0.12761322],
       [ 0.19764288,  0.35325583,  0.17034005],
       [ 0.56812424,  0.48297648,  0.64101657]])
>>> a[[True, False, True]]
array([[ 0.19764288,  0.35325583,  0.17034005],
       [ 0.94362993,  0.3553076 ,  0.12761322],
       [ 0.19764288,  0.35325583,  0.17034005]])
>>> a[np.ix_([True, False, True])]
array([[ 0.94362993,  0.3553076 ,  0.12761322],
      [ 0.56812424,  0.48297648,  0.64101657]])
```

How do I recreate Octave's boolean indexing on Python with Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Indexing with a list `[True, False, True]` is not the same as indexing with a boolean array `array([True,False,True])`. The list will instead be interpreted as integer indexes `[1,0,1]`
2. You need to specify that you only want the results from the first column:

   ```
   >>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
   >>> a
   array([[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]])
   >>> mask = np.array([True,False,True])
   >>> mask.dtype ## verify we have a bool array
   dtype('bool')
   >>> a[mask,0]
   array([0, 6])
   ```